# Is there an easy way to get product info (price, attributes, store availability) from major retailers?

Tags: database

I am looking to build an app that will require info from multiple stores (mostly big retailers, wmt, Amazon, Home Depot maybe, etc) about their product offerings. Most of the info I will require is available on their respective websites, but I was wondering if there would be an easier way to get certain info (such as item name, price, attributes like color, size, and ideally store availability) in an efficient and application friendly manner. I would like to be able to extract this data to a database (or maybe an object which only lives in memory), and go from there to analyze as much as I can get.

It would be possible to crawl their websites, but I have a feeling this would be quite difficult in practice, and could break whenever they make changes to their website (thus potentially unreliable).

I was wondering if anyone knows of any stores that provide an API, spreadsheet, database, or some other means of efficiently gathering this basic product information. I know there are many shopping apps that do stuff like this, do they typically have access to a database or are they all crawling the websites in the background? I am assuming most stores will not be willing to give me access to anything that isn't publicly available, at least not initially.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Many sites provide structured data, e.g., data marked up with the Schema.org vocabulary ([tag:schema.org]), so if you want to crawl, it is advisable to use Microdata/RDFa/JSON-LD parsers to retrieve the structured data instead of scraping the content from the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some sites that may be of interest to you:

- http://www.upcdatabase.com/ http://upcdatabase.org/
- http://www.simpleupc.com/ https://www.outpan.com/
- http://www.grocery.com/open-grocery-database-project/
- http://gepir.prod.gs1us.org/GEPIR/jsp/client.jsp http://eandata.com/
- http://www.ean-search.org/

Often the information found on sites like I've linked to above are crowd-sourced. I'm not aware of any retailer who will willing provide the information you seek.